# Linear memory increase proportional to number of times Model.fit is called

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using tensorflow with custom model to train some ai, and I'm having memory problems. My model consists of 3 different layers that each takes in and processes different information, whose output then together gets fed into a dense network to eventually give me some output.

```
def call(self, x, training=False):
if training:
    xs = []

    for xx in x:
        xx = tf.concat([self.com(xx[0], training), self.hand(xx[1], training), self.rec(xx[2], training)], 1)
        xx = self.out_0(xx)
        xx = self.out_1(xx)
        xs.append(xx)

    return tf.stack(xs)
else:
    x = tf.concat([self.com(x[0], training), self.hand(x[1], training), self.rec(x[2], training)], 1)
    
    x = self.out_0(x)
    x = self.out_1(x)

    return x
```

This is how I wrote the call function for my model. Normally, x is a list of 3 tensors, each representing different input to be fed into different layers. When training, I put in a list where each element in that list is my normal input, as in a list of 3 tensors. I did it like this rather than using dataset because I couldn't find a way to make that work unless I gave up batching without combining those 3 tensors, which was not possible due to difference in shape.

However, for some reason, whenever I call fit on an instance of this model, my memory consumption raises abnormally, which doesn't go away. I have to call fit multiple times, so that's a really huge problem.

And I suspect it might be related to the call function that I wrote, especially the part gated behind training, because when I called fit with dataset at the cost of no batching and removed the gated part due to no longer being needed, the memory issue disappeared. However, I have no idea why.

Also, I think it might be related to default graph somehow creating stuffs and not cleaning them up whenever fit is called, but again I too have no idea how valid that suspicion might be.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. The problem was with how I called fit with python list as input. That caused the tf.function to be newly created whenever it was called, practically, and made memory consumption to hit the skies.